# How can I avoid my label collapsing in my custom checkbox when I have no label text?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have created a custom checkbox and it works as expected as long as I have label text.
But when I remove the label text and only have the checkbox, the row collapses.
I've tried setting the display property for `.kx-selector` to different things, but nothing helps.

How can I avoid having the rows collapsing when not having label text?

[See working example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/Stieng/pen/XWWBVzW).

My code:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 10px; }

 .kx-selector {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
}
 .kx-selector input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
 .kx-selector__indicator {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #71767a;
}
 .kx-selector input:checked ~ .kx-selector__indicator {
  border-color: #007a8c;
  background-color: #007a8c;
}
 .kx-selector input:checked ~ .kx-selector__indicator::before {
  border-color: #f6f6f6;
}
 .kx-selector__checkbox .kx-selector__indicator {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
 .kx-selector__checkbox .kx-selector__indicator:before {
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  border: solid #f6f6f6;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 .kx-selector__checkbox input:checked ~ .kx-selector__indicator::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>

<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>

<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 100% working

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 10px; }

 .kx-selector {
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: center; */     /* Remove this line*/
    flex-direction: column;        /*  Newly added */
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 25px;             /*  Newly added */
}
 .kx-selector input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
 .kx-selector__indicator {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #71767a;
}
 .kx-selector input:checked ~ .kx-selector__indicator {
  border-color: #007a8c;
  background-color: #007a8c;
}
 .kx-selector input:checked ~ .kx-selector__indicator::before {
  border-color: #f6f6f6;
}
 .kx-selector__checkbox .kx-selector__indicator {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
 .kx-selector__checkbox .kx-selector__indicator:before {
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  border: solid #f6f6f6;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 .kx-selector__checkbox input:checked ~ .kx-selector__indicator::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>

<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>

<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `.kx-selector__indicator` position:relative instead of absolute:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.kx-selector {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.kx-selector input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.kx-selector__indicator {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative; /* updated */
  /*left: 0; no more needed */
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right:5px; /* added */
  border: solid 1px #71767a;
}

.kx-selector input:checked~.kx-selector__indicator {
  border-color: #007a8c;
  background-color: #007a8c;
}

.kx-selector input:checked~.kx-selector__indicator::before {
  border-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.kx-selector__checkbox .kx-selector__indicator {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.kx-selector__checkbox .kx-selector__indicator:before {
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  border: solid #f6f6f6;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.kx-selector__checkbox input:checked~.kx-selector__indicator::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>

<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
  <span class="label-text">Select box</span>
</label>

<label class="kx-selector kx-selector__checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <div class="kx-selector__indicator"></div>
</label>
```